# Overloading insertion operator (operator<<)

Tags: c++

I need your help since I can't seem to get my head around any of the (many) various solutions found here on SO and elsewhere on the internet regarding overloading of the insertion operator.

I am to make a "database", consisting of a single vector, of employees which I, among other things, must be able to save to text file.

The code must have one base class called Employees and three derived classes called Manager, Engineer and Researcher.

Based on:

```
for (vector<Employees*>::iterator i = midzer.begin(); i != midzer.end(); ++i)
{
    (*i)->printStats(); 
}

/* printStats is a virtual method outputting all data contained in the objects to 
the console window. It's implemented like so for one of the derived classes:*/

void Manager::printStats()
{
    cout << "\nManager." << endl;
    cout << "First name: " << mFirstName << endl; // data member of base class
    cout << "Last name: " << mLastName << endl; // data member of base class
    cout << "Salary: " << mSalary << endl; // data member of base class
    cout << "Meetings per week: " << mNumberOfMeetingsPerWeek << endl; // data member of derived class
    cout << "Vacation Days per year: " << mNumberOfVacationDaysPerYear << endl; //data member of derived class
    cout << endl;
}
```

I thought I could just create an ostream object like below and voila..

```
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("/users/mundt/desktop/EmployeeDatabase.txt");
for (vector<Employees*>::iterator i = midzer.begin(); i != midzer.end(); ++i)
{
    outfile << (*i)->printStats();
}
outfile.close();
```

As you (probably) know that's not possible and I have to overload the insertion operator for the base class Employees and also make it polymorphic somehow to be able to access the derived class parts as well.

What I'm seeking is a way to use my printStats() method to output the data of all objects in the vector to a text file.

If anyone can provide some sample code to do this, it will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What's an _insertion operator_ in [tag:c++]? Elaborate please! Did you mean `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& ref)` overload??

Comment: Have I stated it wrong? This one <<

Comment: `printStats` sends data directly to `cout`.  I'd recommend passing `printStats` a `std::ostream&` to write to, and then this becomes very easy indeed.

Comment: Maybe `printStats()` should return a string instead, or as @MooingDuck says, pass the `ostream` to the `printStats()` function

Comment: Thank you @Mooing Duck. However, that's what I have trouble doing due to my newbiness so can you be a bit more specific please?

Comment: That operator is technically called the left shift operator

Comment: @MooingDuck Because of the completely different semantics of bitwise left shifts on numeric types, and writing data representations to an output stream, I prefer to see a concrete operator signature for such case!!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In the context of `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& ref)` overloads, the `operator<<` is referred to as the "insertion operator", because the completely different semantics deserves a completely different name.  I'm not sure what you mean about concrete operator signatures here.

Comment: @MooingDuck _' I'm not sure what you mean about concrete operator signatures here'_ Just exposing them at some API doc is fairly enough!

Comment: It's left shift operator

Comment: For everyone climbing down the dark size of vernacular, the web-footed-bovine is (as usual) correct. When used in context of iostreams, both `<<` and `>>` are *often* referred to as "stream insertion operator" and "stream extraction operator" respectively. So no you (the OP) didn't say it wrong. (and a simple google of "C++ stream insertion operator" will reveal the prevalence).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many options for doing this, I will describe 3:

1. Returning a string from the function
2. Outputting to a stream that is passed to the function
3. Overloading `operator<<` (this is used in conjunction with one of the above 2)

More detail:

1. If you return a string from the `printStats()` function then you can write that to your `ofstream`:

   ```
   std::string Manager::printStats()
   {
       std::stringstream ss;
       ss << "\nManager." << endl;
       ss << "First name: " << mFirstName << endl; // data member of base class
       ss << "Last name: " << mLastName << endl; // data member of base class
       ss << "Salary: " << mSalary << endl; // data member of base class
       ss << "Meetings per week: " << mNumberOfMeetingsPerWeek << endl; // data member of derived class
       ss << "Vacation Days per year: " << mNumberOfVacationDaysPerYear << endl; //data member of derived class
       ss << endl;

       return ss.str();
   }
   ```
2. If you pass in an `ostream` to the function, you can output directly to it. (You may want to define the function as `void printStats( std::ostream& os = std::cout );` so if you call it with no parameters, it will default to `cout`:

   ```
   void Manager::printStats( std::ostream& os )
   {
       os << "\nManager." << endl;
       //...
   }
   ```

   This would be called like this in your example:

   ```
   (*i)->printStats( outFile );
   ```
3. If you overload the `operator<<` then you can directly pass it to the `outFile`.

   ```
   std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, const Employee& e )
   {
       os << e.printStats(); 
       // or
       e.printStats( os );

       // for both cases
       return os;
   }
   ```

   Then this could be called:

   ```
   outFile << *(*i);
   ```

Comment: @MooingDuck `*i` gives you a `Employees*`, `*(*i)` gives you an `Employees`

Comment: The first option seems the simplest to me. However, where does the str() method come from? omg I feel stupid..

Comment: [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/str/) : it gives you the `string` out of the `stringstream`

Comment: @clcto Implementing option 1. I get the following error:
Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >'

The error appears on the stringstream ss; line.

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Kenneth I think you need to `#include <sstream>`

Comment: @clcto Included <sstream> in the right .cpp file and the code now compiles. However, nothing is written to the text file.. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: See what @MooingDuck said in the other answer.

Comment: I got it to work the way I wanted this morning using the sstream option. Thank you very much for your help. Have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 2):

First, `printStats` should be told where to put the data, and not just always write it to `cout`.

```
void Manager::printStats(std::ostream& out) const //function doesn't modify, so const
{
    out << "\nManager." << endl;
    out << "First name: " << mFirstName << endl; // data member of base class
    out << "Last name: " << mLastName << endl; // data member of base class
    out << "Salary: " << mSalary << endl; // data member of base class
    out << "Meetings per week: " << mNumberOfMeetingsPerWeek << endl; // data member of derived class
    out << "Vacation Days per year: " << mNumberOfVacationDaysPerYear << endl; //data member of derived class
    out << endl;
}
```

Then tell C++ how to insert your class into a stream:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Employees& employee) 
{
   employee.printStats(out);
   return out; //return ostreams by reference when done
}
```

If you'd like, you can add another for the vector , that does almost exactly what your old loop did

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const vector<Employees*>& midzer) 
{
   for (vector<Employees*>::const_iterator i = midzer.begin(); i != midzer.end(); ++i)
   {
       out << *(*i);
   }
   //or if you have a newer compiler:
   //for (Employees* i : midzer) out << *i;
   return out; //return ostreams by reference when done
}
```

finally, output the vector

```
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("/users/mundt/desktop/EmployeeDatabase.txt");
outfile << midzer; //well that's easy
outfile.close();
```

Working demo here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03fd3b4e23dc7ee2

Comment: I get an error saying: Expected expression. Can you tell why?

Comment: @Kenneth Probably because I made a typo.  Or you may be missing an include.  Where is the error?

Comment: The error is on this line:

for (vector<Employees*>::iterator i = midzer.begin(); i != midzer.end(); ++i)

Comment: @Kenneth: Did you try `vector<Employees*>::const_iterator`?  I can't think of anything on that line that should give "expected expression".  Go to View->Output, and then compile, and look at the full message of the error in that window.

Comment: Not yet, you made some edits I'm trying to implement

Comment: Okay, before you lose me in the edits.

1) the second block you added gives me 2 more errors when implemented.
- Employees does not refer to a value. And.

- use of undeclared identifier "out".

2) I use Xcode version 5.0.2 and don't have a view->output option.

Comment: @Kenneth: "Expected Expression" is also part of an MSVC error message, so I assumed you were using that, sorry.  XCode should show the full error messages by default.  The only thing I can think of that might cause that error is that you don't have a class called `Employees`.  All the code in my answer is valid C++: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cdafd7a3143a7d3

Comment: And `out` is declared in the function declaration: `operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Employees& employee)`.  Does yours not match that?

Comment: The Employees class looks like this:


    class Employees
    {
    public:
        Employees();
        virtual ~Employees();
    
    
        //Accessor methods.
        void setFirstName(string x);
        string getFirstName();
        void setLastName(string x);
        string getLastName();
        void setSalary(int x);
        int getSalary();
    
        virtual void printStats(ostream& out);

    protected:
        string mFirstName;
        string mLastName;
        int mSalary;
    };

Comment: Maybe I'm putting your code in the wrong place. I'm using a .h file for the declarations and a .ccp file for method implementation and a main.cpp.
I have made the changes to the prinStats() method.
The second block I don't know where to put.
The third and forth block are put in main.cpp

Comment: Clicking on the link you provided it seems I am putting your code in the wrong places. I'll make the changes and see what happens (Hopefully it works before the mac goes out the window)

Comment: I got the the code to compile. However, nothing is written to the text file.

Comment: +1 (and seriously, this deserves at least an up-vote from the OP, as this is well-into the extra-mile distance).

Comment: @Kenneth: Try using `cout << midzer;` and see if it can print to the screen.  If it can't, then you have more errors somewhere. If it does, then the ofstream probably can't write to the file properly.

Comment: @WhozCraig Please don't think I'm not extremely grateful for the effort Mooing Duck puts into this (That goes for Mooing Duck too).

Comment: @Kenneth: In the demo (now linked to from the answer itself), I've split the parts into a header and a cpp file.

Comment: Thank you @Mooing Duck you're the man. I finally got the program to do what I wanted. However, by utilising the string stream method provided by clcto. I will try to make the program work using the method you provided also, in order to get a better understanding. Thanks again for your patience. Have wonderful day.

Answer (score 0):

`cout` is a specific `ostream` where the function `PrintStats` is printing to.  What you are looking for instead is overloading `operator<<` for your type.

```
    std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & s, const Employee& m)
    {
        m.Stream(s);
        return s;
    }
```

And then this can be used as:

```
    outfile << *i;
```

And then declare a function `virtual Stream() const` in `Employee` and override it in `Manager`

Comment: Where would i write the first part?

Comment: @Kenneth sorry I didn't read the question fully, I hope the edit is clearer.